# Marketing cloud Journey SMS Error

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, mobile

[image]

I have never seen this error before, can anyone direct me on where to correct this?

This error shows up when trying to activate a journey which first step is to send an sms

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that the system adds a 32character guid to the message name (plus a dash and space) I would suggest only using 66 characters in your mobile message name.

[image]